# Rotating Radar graph Blazorise

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, charts, blazor, blazorise

Currently I am working with Blazorise, which works quite nice.
Now, I have created a radar graph as desired.
However, I need to rotate it a bit (22.5 deg). 
There seems to be no option for this as per https://github.com/stsrki/Blazorise/blob/master/Source/Extensions/Blazorise.Charts/ChartOptions.cs#L118

Is there a workaround or something I could use?

I tried turning the canvas, but that turns the labels aswell, which is not desired.

**The razor page component call:**

```
    <Blazorise.Charts.RadarChart @ref="RadarChart" TItem="double"/>
```

**Drawing the graph component**

```
    async Task HandleRedraw()
    {
        RadarChart.Clear();

        RadarChart.AddLabel(new string[] { "Axis 1","Axis 2", "Axis 4",
             "Axis 5", "Axis 7","Axis 8", "Axis 10", "Axis 11" });

        RadarChart.AddDataSet(GetRadarChartDataset());

        await RadarChart.Update();
    }
```

**Filling the dataset**

```
    RadarChartDataset<double>[] GetRadarChartDataset() {
        RadarChartDataset<double> dataset1 = null;
        dataset1 = new RadarChartDataset<double>
        {
            Label = "Label",
            Data = MyData.ToList(),
            BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor,
            BorderColor = BorderColor,
            Fill = true,
            LineTension = 0

        };
        //More dataset setups
        return new RadarChartDataset<double>[] {
            dataset1, .. , ..
        };
    }
```

**This graph needs to turn 22.5 degree, without moving the labels**

[image: Old]